# Remove flag legend in Highcharter graph

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

How can I remove "Series 2" in the graph below? The documentation points to https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.flags . However, I can't find an example how additional options are added to "...".

```
library("quantmod")
library("highcharter")

usdjpy <- getSymbols("USD/JPY", src="oanda", auto.assign = FALSE)

dates <- as.Date(c("2018-01-08", "2018-01-12"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
highchart(type = "stock") %>% 
  hc_add_series(usdjpy, id = "usdjpy") %>% 
  hc_add_series_flags(dates,
                      title = c("E1", "E2"), 
                      text = c("This is event 1", "This is the event 2"),
                      id = "usdjpy") %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled = T)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the argument `showInLegend = F`:

```
highchart(type = "stock") %>% 
  hc_add_series(usdjpy, id = "usdjpy") %>% 
  hc_add_series_flags(dates,
                      title = c("E1", "E2"), 
                      text = c("This is event 1", "This is the event 2"),
                      id = "usdjpy", showInLegend = F) %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled = T)
```

For more information: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.showInLegend